# MYSQL - Is storing data as enum number values better than storing data with full values?

Tags: mysql, database

In MYSQL, does storing actual values degrade the performance significantly?

In the example below, on the left I am storing actual values. This makes is very easy for presentation purposes. All I need to to is select value from gender table and display it directly.
On the right is where the numbers are stored. "1" represents "female" and I have to create a look up list somewhere in my application to translate the value.

If the performance difference is negligible, I would just go with storing full values.

[image]

Comment: indexing/search is way faster on the integers compared to strings. You should follow normalization principles. Have separate tables for religion_master and gender_master
Although, gender_master has limited values, you can rather use ENUM for it.

Comment: I dislike enums and 'The strings you specify as input values are automatically encoded as numbers' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html

Comment: internally, they are stored as numbers, this is just a "courtesy" of the GUI. Be grateful for it.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - separate tables for religion_master and gender_master  - So there is a second database query to `select religion_master from table where religion = 1` ... Is this still more efficient even with 2 queries instead of just one ?

Comment: searching on integer is much faster than on strings. Anyways you can use JOINs to get all the data at one go, instead of doing two separate queries.